# Highcharts problems

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Can you help me using highcharts api this image client want to see:

[image: enter image description]

Here is my sample code:

```
$(function () {
    var yourLabels = ["Women", "Age", "Men"];
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["", "", ""]
        },
        yAxis: {
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                align: 'center'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: 'white'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
        }, {
            data: [-144.0, -176.0, -135.6]
        }]
    });
});
```

My head is rolling to code a review of highcharts. Thank you in advance!

Comment: or help me find another chart api to customize like a image i linked.

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29793088/edit) if you want to add something to it. No need to add details as a comment.

Comment: can anyone please answer this question [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038680/highcharts-how-to-change-marker-symbol-and-datalabel-with-custom-style-in-highc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set quite a lot of options, mockup for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ptysyo4p/13/

Long story short:

- use multiple x-axes to display categories on top/middle/bottom of the chart, connected them by using `linkedTo` option
- use two y-axes, to display two separate parts of the chart. Manage those positions by `top` and `height`. Second axis is linked to the first one, but is reversed - still can display positive values as I would expect.
- first point is hard one, I suggest to render `transparent` column there to display label and tooltip when hovering that label

And code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true  
    },
    xAxis: [{
        id: "mainAxis",
        top: '52%',
        lineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        categories: ["Age", "18-24", "25-34", "45-54"],
        offset: 0,
        labels: {
            y: -1   
        }
    }, {
        linkedTo: 0,
        showEmpty: true,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        categories: ["46%", "30%", "30%", "30%"],
        opposite: true
    }, {
        linkedTo: 0,
        showEmpty: true,
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        categories: ["54%", "45%", "15%", "30%"],
        opposite: false
    }],
    yAxis: [{
        height: '45%',
        offset: 0,
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        endOnTick: true
    }, {
        top: '55%',
        height: '45%',
        reversed: true,
        linkedTo: 0,
        offset: 0,
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        endOnTick: true
    }],

    series: [{
        borderWidth: 0,
        name: "Women",
        data: [{
            y: 46,
            color: "transparent",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: true,
                verticalAlign: "bottom",
                format: "Women"
            }
        },
        30, 30, 30],
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        borderWidth: 0,
        name: "Men",
        data: [{
            y: 54,
            color: "transparent",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: true,
                verticalAlign: "top",
                format: "Men"
            }
        }, 45, 15, 30],
        yAxis: 1
    }]
});
```

Now of course, you need to deal with colors, backgrounds etc. Note that some of the options are set to fit for that specific height of the chart, like `xAxis[0].labels.y`.

Comment: thanks for doing that for me.. i really appreciated.

Comment: Hi i have a bug if women value is lower than men value andr have a value of 50+ the bar will goes down in the max bottom.https://jsfiddle.net/ptysyo4p/16/

Comment: You can always set yAxis.max, example: https://jsfiddle.net/ptysyo4p/19/ Note: it's hard to compare values like 5000 vs 15 ;) You can play around with `minPointLength`