# How to Change marker symbol and dataLabel with custom style in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can we customize dataLables and marker symbol on hover? Please refer to the following image:

[image: **image**]

Comment: What do you have and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This feels like a "give me the code" question. Please refer to this [discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593)

Comment: i did some research before bellow are the example fiddles i have
[**1.Fiddle ONE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbmu4sat/5/), 
[**2.Fiddle TWO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtgbmas7/)
@HalvorStrand

Comment: @Deep3015 Please refer the 2 Jsfiddles above thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add symbols as image (url link) inside markers to the last data in the series

[Fork Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpxrLcad/2/) explore it

```
    series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,{
        y: 26.5,
        dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
        marker: {
        radius: 10,
        symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)',
    }
    }],
}, {
  data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5,{
        y: 103.9,
        dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
        marker: {
        radius: 10,
        symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)',
    }
    }],
}],
```

**Edit**

According to new requirement

```
        series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
         point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function(e) {
          this.series.data.forEach(p => {
            p.update({
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              marker: {
              radius: 10,
              symbol: 'circle',
          }
            }, false, false)
          });

          this.update({
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            },
             marker: {
            radius: 10,
            symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)',
            }

          });
        }
      }
    }
}, {
  data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5],
   point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function(e) {
          this.series.data.forEach(p => {
            p.update({
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              marker: {
              radius: 10,
              symbol: 'circle',
          }
            }, false, false)
          });

          this.update({
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            },
             marker: {
            radius: 10,
            symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)',
            }

          });
        }
      }
    }
}],
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zpxrLcad/3/)

**Update**
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zpxrLcad/5/)

Comment: i already tried that but the point is i want to show them only on hove for each point.. i searched every where but no luck :(
@Deep3015

Comment: event `mouseOut` I have omittted. if you want in original state on mouse out you can add it to respective series

Comment: adding mouse out changing only one series :( 
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zpxrLcad/4/)
will you please solve this issue @Deep3015

Comment: i am looking it

Comment: hi Deep still there is a problem in mouseout i tried to solve it but failed.
Please Check the ****[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zpxrLcad/6/)****
when we moving cursor up & down symbols and labels are toggling..
Please help me on this @Deep3015

Comment: please post this problem as new question.See some body resolves it